# Reading Multiple Text Inputs into a Function in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have a situation where I want to have a button such as "Add Via" and the user can then add multiple via options in a distance calculation to look at the distance between two points.
I have read elsewhere how to read in multiple textboxes to add data to. However, I'm unclear how to then read the output from multiple textboxes into the function.

How can I work the "via" option for the multiple textboxes?

The current code is given below.

```
airport_distance_1 <- function(departing_airport_code, arriving_airport_code, via = NULL){
  
  airports <- c(departing_airport_code, via, arriving_airport_code)
  
  if (length(airports) == 2) {
    distance <- airportr::airport_distance(airports[1], airports[2])
  } else {
    distance1 <- NULL
    for (m in 2:length(airports)-1){
      distance1[m] <- airportr::airport_distance(airports[m], airports[m+1])
    }
    distance <- sum(distance1)
  }
  
  return(distance)
}


ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  
  sidebarPanel(
    textInput(inputId = "from_airport", label = "From:", value = "LAX", width = "41%"),
    textInput(inputId = "to_airport", label = "To:", value = "LHR", width = "41%"),
    
    h4("Via:"),
    actionButton("add_btn", "+"),
    actionButton("rm_btn", "-"),
    textOutput("counter")
    
  ),
  
  mainPanel(uiOutput("textbox_ui"),
            splitLayout(textOutput("calc")))
  
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  
  # Track the number of input boxes to render
  counter <- reactiveValues(n = 0)
  
  observeEvent(input$add_btn, {counter$n <- counter$n + 1})
  observeEvent(input$rm_btn, {
    if (counter$n > 0) counter$n <- counter$n - 1
  })
  
  #output$counter <- renderPrint(print(counter$n))
  
  textboxes <- reactive({
    
    n <- counter$n
    
    if (n > 0) {
      lapply(seq_len(n), function(i) {
        textInput(inputId = paste0("textin", i),
                  label = paste0("Variable", i), value = "")
      })
    }
    
  })
  
  output$textbox_ui <- renderUI({ textboxes() })
  
  summary_calc <- reactive(
    airport_distance_1(departing_airport_code = input$from_airport,
                       arriving_airport_code = input$to_airport,
                       via = input$Variable1)
  )
  
  output$calc <- renderText({
    summary_calc()
  })
  
  
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Ideally I would want to be able to read, say,

`airport_distance_1("LAX", "LHR", via = c("NBO", "DUB"))`

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After having a look and coming across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42169380/shiny-renderui-with-multiple-inputs?rq=1) post I have been able to amend the code to get it to update:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  
  sidebarPanel(
    textInput(inputId = "from_airport", label = "From:", value = "LAX", width = "41%"),
    textInput(inputId = "to_airport", label = "To:", value = "LHR", width = "41%"),
    
    numericInput("NoVars", "Via:", 
                 value = 0, min = 0),
    
    uiOutput("VarsInput")

  ),
  
  mainPanel(
    verbatimTextOutput("train_emissions")
  )
  
))

# Define the server code
server <- function(input, output){
  
  K <- reactive({
    input$NoVars
  })
  
  output$VarsInput <- renderUI({
    NoV = K()
    
    if (NoV == 0){
      L = 0
      output = NULL
    } else {
      L = sapply(1:NoV, function(i){paste0("via_",i)})
      output = tagList()
      
      for(i in seq_along(1:NoV)){
        output[[i]] = tagList()
        output[[i]][[1]] = textInput(L[i], label = "Label for via:", 
                                     value = "Label for via here")
      } ## for loop
    }
    output
  })
  
  output$train_emissions <- renderPrint({
    if (input$NoVars == 0){
      C <- NULL
    } else {
      C <- sapply(1:K(), function(i) {input[[paste0("via_",i)]]})
    }

    airport_distance_1(departing_airport_code = input$from_airport,
                       arriving_airport_code = input$to_airport,
                       via = C)
    
  })
  
}

# Return a Shiny app object
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```